# How to receive json object from servlets with ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, json, servlets

doGet sets item readState new value and sends it back to ajax call as Json object:

```
PrintWriter out = null;
            try {
                out = resp.getWriter();

                Integer read = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("feedReadVal"));

                Gson data = new Gson();
                JsonObject jsonObj = new JsonObject();
                Integer readState = null;
                Item item = new Item();

                readState = 1;
                item.setReadState(readState.byteValue());
                JsonElement element = data.toJsonTree(item);

                jsonObj.add("read", element);
                out.print(jsonObj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Calling:
      `System.out.println("JSON OBJECT: " + jsonObj.toString());` shows something like this `JSON OBJECT: {"read":{"readState":1}}` but when I try to get that data in success function error thrown.My jQuery:

```
var data = "feedReadVal=" + itemRead + "&feedItemId=" + feedItemId
        + "&action=" + 'read';
$.ajax({
    type : "Get",
    url : "FeedItemController",
    data : data,
    dataType : "json",

    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        alert(data.read.readState);
    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("Something really bad happened ");
    }

}).done(function() {

});
```

I receive error alert all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of printing, you need to write it to the stream

change `out.print(jsonObj);` to

```
out.write(jsonObj.toString());
out.flush();
```

Comment: I find the solution,you need to flush after write into stream.

Comment: ha ha, about to say that, glad that you found

Comment: I can accept your answer if you add that information